# Is there a "Disperse Markers" tool for QGIS?

Tags: qgis, point, overlapping-features

I am using ArcGIS, but either I would like to use QGIS and maybe want to switch completely later. 
A have a point overlapping problem, as a result of geocoding of addresses.

I have not found any tool in QGIS which could replace the "Disperse Markers" tool from ArcGIS, because if I understand well, the "Points displacement" tool in QGIS can displace the overlapping polygons only in "circle way" which has finally a very artificial effect.

Please check out these two short articles about Disperse Markers to see what I mean. Please if you know any possible solution in QGIS for this, let me know.

http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2008/08/01/how-to-scatter-marker-symbols-for-stacked-or-clustered-point-features/

Answer (score 4):

I think you are looking for the **Point displacement renderer** as illustrated in https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/57366/187

[image]